# Rejection after rejection, do I keep trying?

Tags: interviewing, job-change, united-kingdom, rejection

I've had three jobs in what I do for 2 years, 3 years and currently 4. Each time I have gone for a new job I have got it instantly and not had any problems. Now suddenly I cannot get anywhere. I don't think i'm doing anything wrong, but the constant rejection is really getting me down. Has anyone else had this experience.. do I give up for a while and start again? Over the last 6 months I must have had 10 interviews.. maybe more, all coming close but the other person was chosen..

So has anyone else had this experience? Did you get to where you wanted to be in the end?

### Edit 1:

I'm in the UK. Still in my current role, the only negative could be that the company I am in isn't great.

### Edit 2:

Thank you everyone for your comments, you've helped me understand and made me feel better about this situation, thanks again.

Comment: Are you still employed? Was there any negative incident at your current job or the previous? Is your country in a bad economic phase?

Comment: Yes, keep trying.

Comment: You're getting interviewed, so you're good enough. You're just unlucky that someone they liked a bit better had got the job. I've lost count of the number of rejections I've received - but I focus on the wins.

Comment: Are you listing skills you had 4 years ago? You have 9 years of total experience in your field so maybe your resume don't reflect that you're a senior level person or you're applying to less than senior roles.

Comment: Ten is virtually nothing. Also remember as you move out of entry level, the competition is much greater and expectations are higher.

Comment: Rejections are part of the life. I am very senior in my field and I've had my own share of rejections after interviews. 10 interviews in a year is not too many. Don't feel down, just try improving your skill set and look at these interviews as  learning experiences.

Answer (score 1):

> Each time I have gone for a new job I have got it instantly and not had any problems

Your mileage will vary wildly. This has not been my experience. It took me more than 6 months to get another job after 2 years and change. I can tell you that 10 interviews was the warm-up period. I used each and every one to refine my approach, until I finally found an excellent company that made me a great offer.

You might not think you're doing anything wrong, but the evidence suggests otherwise. What worked for me was learning how to think like a business person (a bit counter-intuitive as an engineer), and also how to fix my presentation and soft skills. Again, your mileage will vary.

I suggest you work towards a backup plan. My plan was to ask my manager what I can do better, so that in 6-9 months I can have a nice raise, outside of the formal annual review cycle. That way if the job search didn't pan out I'd have a cozier job to fall back to, and that helped my morale quite a bit.

In the meantime there were some weeks I couldn't schedule enough phone interviews, and others with complete radio silence from any leads. When it rains it pours is the saying I believe. I realized that was the normal rhythm of the game and not worry too much if I didn't pursue a lead every day.

A slightly crazy idea is to shift your mindset: You'll get interviewed for a lot of jobs but will only accept one. So, don't think about getting one job, think about getting rejected by X per month. For a while my opening gambit became *Let me tell you why you shouldn't hire me*. If this seems suicidal, you are essentially preempting the well-known *What is your weakness* question, but, if done confidently, it's dressed in a veneer of professionalism and a desire not to waste anyone's time.

I keep editing this question to add a paragraph or two, so I think I'll stop now. I hope you find some of this useful.

Answer (score 1):

**A lot will depend on which job you want and how much money you want to earn.**

Maybe a couple of years ago you were happy to take almost any job to get started. And maybe now you want a job doing this and that under those conditions. That is obviously more difficult.

**Make sure you match your expectations with reality. I.e. if you want a job which requires lots of experience in a certain field make sure you have that experience - otherwise there is not much point to apply for that job.**

Make also sure to look at more than just your "technical" qualifications. I.e. some people know a lot about technology and they think because they know more than others they should get i.e. the team leader job. But that job requires a lot more than just technical knowledge. Make sure you don't overlook these "other" requirements when you look for a job.